# Vercel - No metadata for "Entity" was found - TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, entity, typeorm, vercel

i have a problem with my Node API (MySQL DB) and maybe on .ENV file for TypeORM configurations (I'm not using ormconfig.js/ts/json)

In my local, the API works 100%, and i can do whatever i want using get,post,put,delete methods in all my endpoints.

But when i put/upload the API on Vercel and try to access any endpoint (which works on local), i receive in the screen an error message with the text " No metadata for "Entity Name" was found ".

I imagined the problem can be with .ENV entries on Vercel Panel, but i download (using pull) the .ENV file from Vercel through Vercel CLI, and my local still 100% works, but the problem still remain on Vercel like i said on the beginning.

Bellow follows a screenshot of Vercel Entries and my .ENV file entries.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZIB6.png)

Anyone knows why the error is showed only in Vercel ?

I tried change my Vercel entries and use to JS file, but still not working